# Curves in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Just wanted to know if matlab had a function to plot curves instead of lines. Thank you in advance.

Comment: A "curve" is just a series of small line segments. If you make the line segments small enough (i.e. make the points on the curve close enough together), the plot will look like a smooth curve.

Comment: @gnovice, I don't agree with your first sentence: You can approximate many curves with line segments, but a curve is a rather more general mathematical concept...

Comment: @Jonas: I'm speaking with respect to how plotting is done in MATLAB, not general mathematical concepts.

Answer (score 4):

No. Not at all. Just plot a set of many points, using connect-the-dots. Use enough points to get the accuracy you want. Any curve that you can plot will be well represented by such a piecewise linear plot anyway, if you use a fine enough set of points.

If all that you have are a set of points, then use a spline to interpolate them smoothly to get a nice smooth looking curve. Spline, interp1, pchip, or the splines toolbox will help you in this task.

Answer (score 4):

An example of using `spline` to interpolate then plot the result:

```
x = 0:2:6*pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y, 'b-'), hold on

xx = 0:0.1:6*pi;
yy = spline(x,y,xx);
plot(xx, yy, 'r-', 'linewidth',2)
```

[screenshot http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2180c0813b.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2180c0813b.png)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, MATLAB proves a suite of "easy" (= "ez") plotting functions.  For example:

ezplot:

```
ezplot('x^2 - y^2')
```

and ezsurf:

```
fh = @(x,y) sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2);
ezsurf(fh)
```

See http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ezplot.html for more information

Answer (score 0):

**Curve Fitting with Matlab**
http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/MatlabCurveFit/MatlabCftool.html

Comment: OP asked for plotting curves, not fitting curves.

Comment: Well if you're gonna plot it, you gotta fit it first either way. It all comes down to linear segments at the bottom ... the detail is only whether you're determining what's in between or some intrinsic function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like [splines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)) then yes, just use the `spline` function

Comment: there's a "spline" function (http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/spline.html) but it is curve-interpolating, not plotting. (is there a "splines" function?)

Comment: but if you can interpolate it, shouldn't you be able to plot it?

Comment: defintly, but the question I believe was not worded correctly, yet everyone understood what he meant ;) The questioner said he wants to plot a curve while in reality he already had a set of points that he wanted to plot smothely (for example using splines)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [Curve Fitting Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/curvefitting/)?